# How does this macro work?

Tags: python, c, macros, micropython

In [this Python implementation](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/unix/modmachine.c#L80) for microcontrollers, they use C-macro like follows:

```
MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_mem16)
```

with:

```
#define MP_ROM_QSTR(q) MP_OBJ_NEW_QSTR(q)
```

and:

```
#define MP_OBJ_NEW_QSTR(qst) ((mp_obj_t)((((mp_uint_t)(qst)) << 2) | 2))
```

My issue is: `MP_QSTR_mem16` seems to be never defined!

So, how does this work?

Comment: So if your question about the macro definition, or where `MP_QSTR_mem16` might be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro works as any macros do by text replacement.  The original code

```
MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_mem16)
```

gets replaced in two steps, first it is reduced to

```
MP_OBJ_NEW_QSTR(MP_QSTR_mem16)
```

which is reduced to

```
((mp_obj_t)((((mp_uint_t)(MP_QSTR_mem16)) << 2) | 2))
```

This finally is passed to the C/C++ compiler.

When you say that the term `MP_QSTR_mem16` is "never defined" then this can be true.  It being defined or not is not related to the use of this macro here.  This macro is not supposed to be a *definition* or *declaration* of the term `MP_QSTR_mem16`, but instead it is a *use* of the term.

The macro generates an expression which will cast `MP_QSTR_mem16` to the type `mp_uint_t`, then it left-shifts the resulting value by two bits, binary-ors the resulting value with `2` and casts the result to the type `mp_obj_t`.  Nothing of this defines or declares the value it started with.

You might want to find out where the value `MP_QSTR_mem16` should come from.

EDIT

After having a look into the source you point to I also had trouble finding the declaration of `MP_QSTR_mem16`.  It seems to me that the term specifier `MP_QSTR_mem16` is *created* by concatenating some strings.  This can be done in the C/C++ preprocessor using the `##` operator.  If you search for `MP_QSTR_ ##` in the code you find several occurrences like this one:

```
./micropython-master/teensy/mk20dx256_prefix.c:    .name = MP_QSTR_ ## p_port ## p_pin, \
```

Effectively, the place where `MP_QSTR_mem16` is actually defined can also look something like this:

```
#define FOO(x) MP_QSTR_ ## x
```

(… and later, somewhere …)

```
int FOO(mem16);
```

But despite searching for some time in the source I did not find such a place.  It can be very nastily hidden deeply within macro logic.  A suitable way to find the place can be to tweak the compiler to write out the result of the preprocessor; in this you should be able to find it (but this is well beyond the topic of this question, so if you have trouble using this approach, please ask another question).

Comment: Thanks. This put me on the right track. It appears, that a makefile calls a python script, which parses the preprocessor output to auto-generate a header file with these missing definitions. If anybody else is curious have a look at: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/py/makeqstrdefs.py

Comment: Sounds … peculiar, to be diplomatic.  Deeply disturbing was my first shot.